# pyqtgraph.DateAxisItem : How to use other language on x-axis?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph

When i use the DateAxisItem to display data, it works perfect. But i want to display other language on x-axis. Now it display as English, such as Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun...How to modify to display other language?

Comment: That depends. You can set the locale for the application, which will potentially translate every string that supports localization. But if you want to *specifically* localize only that part, it's a bit tricky

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, You should set locale for Your running application.
That's rather easy, this example set Your locale to German:

```
import locale
import sys
from datetime import datetime

import pyqtgraph as pg
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'de_DE.utf8')
    list_x = [datetime(2021, i + 1, 1, 10, 00, 00, 0) for i in range(12)]
    list_y = range(len(list_x))

    date_axis = pg.DateAxisItem(orientation='bottom')
    graph = pg.PlotWidget(axisItems={'bottom': date_axis})

    graph.plot(x=[x.timestamp() for x in list_x], y=list_y, pen=None, symbol='o')
    graph.show()

    app.exec()
```

**But what if You want to localize different plots in different languages (locales)?**
We can create new DateAxisItem which will take target locale as a argument and do exactly that!
By re-implementing `tickStrings` method we can change locale to target one first, generate our strings and then revert back to default locale.
Here is the code example:

```
import locale
import sys
from datetime import datetime

import pyqtgraph as pg
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication


class LocalizedTimeline(pg.DateAxisItem):

    def __init__(self, target_locale, orientation='bottom', default_locale=None, utcOffset=None, **kwargs):
        """Choose target_locale which will localize date string"""
        self.target_locale = target_locale
        # Set default locale to current one if default_locale is empty
        self.default_locale = ".".join(locale.getlocale(locale.LC_TIME)) if default_locale is None else default_locale
        super().__init__(orientation=orientation, utcOffset=utcOffset, **kwargs)

    def tickStrings(self, values, scale, spacing):
        # Set locale to target one
        locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, self.target_locale)
        # Generate date strings using target locale
        strings = super().tickStrings(values, scale, spacing)
        # Switch back to default locale
        locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, self.default_locale)
        return strings


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    list_x = [datetime(2021, i + 1, 1, 10, 00, 00, 0) for i in range(12)]
    list_y = range(len(list_x))

    # One plot in English localization
    date_axis = LocalizedTimeline('en_US.UTF-8', orientation='bottom')
    graph = pg.PlotWidget(axisItems={'bottom': date_axis})
    graph.plot(x=[x.timestamp() for x in list_x], y=list_y, pen=None, symbol='o')
    graph.show()

    # One plot in German localization
    date_axis2 = LocalizedTimeline('de_DE.utf8', orientation='bottom')
    graph2 = pg.PlotWidget(axisItems={'bottom': date_axis2})
    graph2.plot(x=[x.timestamp() for x in list_x], y=list_y, pen=None, symbol='o')
    graph2.show()

    app.exec()
```

That should show us two same timeline plots in different languages.

**Notes**:

1. I used copy pasting of plot creation for better code explanation
2. I used Python 3.8 for this example. Locale strings might be different for different python versions.
3. Also line `self.default_locale = ".".join(locale.getlocale(locale.LC_TIME)) if default_locale is None else default_locale` may be adjusted with different Python version to work properly.